# Python - How to search a dictionary for a specific string?

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have a dictionary defined as `users = {}`, and lets say I have some data in that dictionary, how could I search through the dictionary, and do nothing if my search string matches a string in my dictionary.

```
for socket.user in MyServer.users:
    if ((MyServer.users.has_key(socket.user)) == false):
        MyServer.users[user].send(socket.message)
```

So here is searches the users dictionary, and finds that it is present, so it should do nothing. I know my code is wrong, but what could I change on the second line?

Answer (score 5):

```
users = {"A": 0, "B": 1, "C": 2}

key = "B"
value = "2"

if key in users: print("users contains key", key)
if value in users.values(): print("users contains value", value)
```

Comment: Instead of `if key in users.keys()`, you can just use `if key in users` -- it means the same thing.

Comment: `{}` does not define a set, it's always a dictionary. (Even in Python 3 where you can use `{...}` for set literals.)

Comment: FWIW, Python 2.7 also understands set literals.  2.6 does not.

Comment: @atomAltera could you edit your answer since you wrote something inaccurate. thanks

Answer (score 3):

> How could I search through the dictionary, and do nothing if my search string matches a string in my dictionary.

```
if socket.user in MyServer.users: # search if key is in dictionary
   pass # do nothing
```

Comment: Um... if a user shows up in the `for`/`in` loop, isn't the `not in` test guaranteed to be false?

Answer (score 1):

In python, you can use the [`pass`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) keyword to essentially 'do nothing'.

```
for socket.user in MyServer.users:
    if MyServer.users.has_key(socket.user) == False:
        pass
```

However the more proper way would be to write your code in a manner that does what you WANT it to do; not doing what you don't NEED it to do.

```
for socket.user in MyServer.users:
    if MyServer.users.has_key(socket.user) == True:
        MyServer.users[user].send(socket.message)
```

Comment: Assuming `MyServer.users` is a normal Python dictionary, the `for`/`if` combination is wasteful, and a simple `in` (or `not in`) test would be much much faster.

Comment: @DanielPryden You are correct; an `in/not in` would be quicker than the method the question asker portrayed.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something, or is this what you are looking for:

```
if socket.user in MyServer.users:
    # Send a message if it's a valid user
    MyServer.users[user].send(socket.message)
else:
    # Do nothing if it isn't
    pass
```

Comment: Unneeded `else` statement though with the singular command of `pass`.

Comment: @PenguinCoder: Indeed.  I only added it to make the flow clear to the OP.